# How to get authenticated to Redis Cloud Memcached using Spymemcached?

Tags: redis, memcached, sasl, spymemcached

I am trying to connect to Redis Cloud Memcached  but get an error (below). I have checked that the username, password, host, and port are correct in the apps.redislabs.com interface. I able to connect if I disable SASL and connect unauthenticated.

How can I diagnose this?

(Using spymemcached 2.11.6.)

```
import net.spy.memcached.auth.*;
import net.spy.memcached.*;
...
List<InetSocketAddress> addresses = Collections.singletonList(addr);
AuthDescriptor ad = new AuthDescriptor(new String[] { "CRAM-MD5", "PLAIN" },
        new PlainCallbackHandler(user, password));
MemcachedClient mc = new MemcachedClient(new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
       .setProtocol(ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol.BINARY)
       .setAuthDescriptor(ad).build(),
AddrUtil.getAddresses(host + ":" + port));
```

The stacktrace:

```
net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=pub-memcache-14154.us-central1-1-1.gce.garantiadata.com/104.197.191.74:14514, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Discarding partially completed op: SASL auth operation
net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to exception on {QA sa=pub-memcache-14154.us-central1-1-1.gce.garantiadata.com/104.197.191.74:14514, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReads(MemcachedConnection.java:820)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReadsAndWrites(MemcachedConnection.java:720)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:683)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:436)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:1446)
 net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=pub-memcache-14154.us-central1-1-1.gce.garantiadata.com/104.197.191.74:14514, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}, attempt 0.
net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for foo.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the `"CRAM-MD5"` in your `AuthDescriptior` declaration.

The following works in my tests: (user, pass, and url removed)

```
AuthDescriptor ad = new AuthDescriptor(new String[] {"PLAIN"}, new PlainCallbackHandler(user, pass));
MemcachedClient mc = null;
    try {
        mc = new MemcachedClient(
        new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
            .setProtocol(ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol.BINARY)
            .setAuthDescriptor(ad).build(),
        AddrUtil.getAddresses(host + ":" + port ));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
mc.set("foo", 0, "bar");
String value = (String) mc.get("foo");
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: The OP should have contacted Redis Labs' support... oh, I see everyone's here anyway ;)

Comment: That did it! Does using PLAIN reduce the security?